# How to work with StateManager gxt 3

Tags: java, gxt

I'm trying to get the value of CookieProvider the following method:

```
public void getValue(){
    StateManager.get().get("idReg", String.class, new Callback<String, Throwable>() {            
    public void onFailure(Throwable reason) {
        state = "";
    }
    public void onSuccess(String result) {
    state = result; 
        });    
}
```

issued the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.JsniCreatorMap$.create$(JsniCreatorMap.java:44) 
at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.AbstractAutoBeanFactory.     
create(AbstractAutoBeanFactory.java:38) at    
com.sencha.gxt.state.client.StateManager.getDefaultStateInstance(StateManager.java:90)
at com.sencha.gxt.state.client.StateManager$1.onSuccess(StateManager.java:73)
at com.sencha.gxt.state.client.StateManager$1.onSuccess(StateManager.java:1)
at com.sencha.gxt.state.client.CookieProvider.getValue(CookieProvider.java:54)
at com.sencha.gxt.state.client.StateManager.get(StateManager.java:64)
at com.rfrate.exrate.client.NorthComponent.setComboValue(NorthComponent.java:46)
at com.rfrate.exrate.client.NorthComponent.asWidget(NorthComponent.java:102)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.asWidgetOrNull(Widget.java:46)
at com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.Container.add(Container.java:72)
at com.rfrate.exrate.client.ExRate.createNorth(ExRate.java:52) 
at com.rfrate.exrate.client.ExRate.onModuleLoad(ExRate.java:97) ... 9 more
```

Can anyone give an example of code to read and write variable String value in a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about using StateManager, but to read write cookies it's simply:

Write:

```
  //javax.servlet.http.Cookie
Cookie localUserId = new Cookie("cookieName", user_info.getLocalDataId());nick_name.setPath("/");
nick_name.setMaxAge(36 * 24 * 60 * 60);
  //appengine specific
this.getThreadLocalResponse().addCookie(localUserId);
```

Read:

```
    //com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies;
Cookies.getCookie("cookieName"));
```

Comment: In gxt 2.X was an excellent way: StateManager.get (). getString ()